# React and Three.js MTLLoader "material.onBeforeCompile is undefined"

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I'm trying to build a simple object-viewer in React with Meteor that can import .obj and .mtl Files using the following npm modules:

- three(0.87.1)
- react(15.6.1)
- three-obj-loader(1.1.3)
- three-mtl-loader(1.0.1)

So far i have managed to display an object using the OBJLoader.
But when i try to render an object after applying a texture with MTLLoader, i get this error from console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
>       at WebGLPrograms.getProgramCode (modules.js?hash=eae498e3ee56e21f967b663c5bed3444c66eaef2:50707)
>       at initMaterial (modules.js?hash=eae498e3ee56e21f967b663c5bed3444c66eaef2:54628)
>       at setProgram (modules.js?hash=eae498e3ee56e21f967b663c5bed3444c66eaef2:54820)
>       at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (modules.js?hash=eae498e3ee56e21f967b663c5bed3444c66eaef2:53883)
>       at renderObject (modules.js?hash=eae498e3ee56e21f967b663c5bed3444c66eaef2:54613)
>       at renderObjects (modules.js?hash=eae498e3ee56e21f967b663c5bed3444c66eaef2:54586)
>       at WebGLRenderer.render (modules.js?hash=eae498e3ee56e21f967b663c5bed3444c66eaef2:54350)
>       at WebGlDisplay.renderScene (WebGlDisplay.jsx:86)
>       at onClick (WebGlDisplay.jsx:90)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.boundFunc (modules.js?hash=eae498e3ee56e21f967b663c5bed3444c66eaef2:8794)

Cause: *material.onBeforeCompile* in *getProgramCode* is undefined

My code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import THREE from 'three'
const MTLLoader = require('three-mtl-loader');
const OBJLoader = require('three-obj-loader')(THREE);

export default class WebGlDisplay extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

      //init canvas
   init(){
    const width = this.mount.clientWidth;
    const height = this.mount.clientHeight;
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
    renderer.setClearColor('#000000', 0.2);
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    camera.position.set(3,4,6);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());
    this.scene = scene;
    this.camera = camera;
    this.renderer = renderer;
    this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
  }

  //load & render object
  drawOBJ(){
    const mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
    let onProgress = function(e){console.log("rendering:" + e)};
    let onError = function(e){console.log("error:" + e)};
    mtlLoader.load("eagle.mtl", materials => {
        materials.preload();
        // OBJ Loader
        const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        this.materials = materials;
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.load("eagle.obj", object => {
              this.object = object;
            this.scene.add(object);
        }, onProgress, onError);
    }, onProgress,onError);
    this.renderScene();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.init();
    this.drawOBJ();
  }

  renderScene() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={(e) => this.renderScene()}
        style={{ width: '800px', height: '600px' }}
        ref={(mount) => { this.mount = mount }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why i get this error? 
I've tried to use different .obj- and .mtl-files, but the error remains (whenever i try to call *renderScene()*).

By any chance, could it be a problem with the module versions, or maybe some timing problems while loading?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to avoid this `=>` "arrow function" and use more clear and explicit code... I don't know how this `=>` precisely works, but this appear to me another false good-idea of the elastic Javascript syntax... mostly in a context where references must be consistants and reliable... I'am not a Javascript guru, but coming from C/C++, this kind of thing make to me the same effect than a match in a gunpowder magazine.

Comment: Hmmm, can you look at the source of three and see if it has `onBeforeCompile` defined on a material? Are you absolutely sure you are using 87?

Comment: is there any chance you could post this code, so we can track it down and see what is going on? This looks like a bug, but nothing stands out as obvious.

Comment: arrow functions are perfectly normal JavaScript nowadays. @Sedenion I suggest you learn them. They aren't going away. There is absolutely nothing wrong with them. They are the recommended way to do many things in modern JavaScript.

Comment: Yes the version is definitely 87 @pailhead . 
So far I couldn't really wrap my head around the three source.
I didn't find any direct definition of onBeforeCompile except for an empty function in Object.assign in Material.js (i don't even understand if it is called somewhere or not).
Sorry, it seems i am not very helpful here.
Is there a method to put this node/react stuff online without hosting it yourself? (i don't know a fitting method, but i'm pretty new to this whole stuff anyway)

Comment: It is lol, id like to claim that callback as my idea, but I don't like the implementation, I think that mine was much better and would probably avoid problems like this. With that being said, it is an empty function. The reason for this is to save checking if it exists and instead just execute it. You are supposed to provide the callback if you want to modify the shader code, but in a super clunky way.

Comment: Can you post about this here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11475

Comment: Do you know if there is a quick solution for this that i can do in the MTLLoader source to fix this for me @pailhead ? Is it necessary to post this on the Git Repo again as you already linked this discussion there, I don't know if it'd be of any use if i report the issue there again.

Comment: Probably doesn't, can you share the obj and mtl somewhere?

Comment: I took it from here: https://free3d.com/3d-model/eagle-2-59246.html

note: for simplicity i changed the src-name in the code above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the three-mtl-loader NPM package is referencing an outdated three.js version in it's package.json, so even though you are using the latest version of three, the plugin isn't!

Obviously this isn't a viable long-term fix, but I changed the version for three in `node_modules/three-mtl-loader/package.json` to 0.87.1 and deleted the directory `node_modules/three-mtl-loader/node_modules` for good measure and ran my example and it worked straight away, textures and all.

Clearly the plugin needs to be updated. I also saw at least one functional difference between the source in the plugin and in the three examples folder ('Tr' vs 'tr' in a case statement), and it doesn't follow the same initialization behavior as other loader plugins (specifically it isn't initialized by calling `require("three-mtl-loader")(THREE)`), so there's a bit of work to get it ship-shape.

Alternately, it appears that the author has updated the version number to 0.86.0 in their repo (which is high enough), just hasn't done a deploy to NPM. So, if you feel brave, you can just change your package.json to have the line

`"dependencies": {
...
    "three-mtl-loader": "git+https://git@github.com/nascherman/three-mtl-loader.git",
...
  }`

Comment: spot on! My own depepdency had a different Three.js version than that of my own app that consumed my dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, what i ended up doing is to get a local copy of the newest [MTLLoader Version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js) and slightly modifing it, as it seems to be a [problem with the version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47026368/8788847) pointed out by @user1691694.
In case somebody needs this here my way of importing it:

In the MTLLoader file, add the following line at the top:

```
import THREE from 'three';
```

and at the bottom:

```
module.exports.default =  THREE.MTLLoader
```

Use it like in the drawOBJ function in the [question post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46787166/8788847) and import it in the target file like this:

```
import MTLLoader from './MTLLoader.js';
```